# How to include Spring Security in a spring boot application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am working of a spring boot application. After developing the application, we are now trying to include spring security in our application.

I have included the following code:

html code:

```
<li th:if="${#authorization.expression('!isAuthenticated()')}">
<a th:href="@{/login}" th:text="#{navbar.login.text}" />
                    </li>
```

Java code:

```
package com.devopsbuddy.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {
            "/webjars/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/",
            "/about/**",
            "/contact/**",
            "/error/**/*"           
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {



        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/payload")
                .failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

when I try to hit the url:

http://localhost:8080/

I am getting the below error on screen:

```
**36673 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-2] Exception processing template "user/login": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('!isAuthenticated()')" (template: "common/navbar" - line 24, col 25)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('!isAuthenticated()')" (template: "common/navbar" - line 24, col 25)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:290)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:125)
...
...

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method expression(java.lang.String) on null context object
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:153)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:67)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:111)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:328)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:263)
    ... 102 common frames omitted

36673 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authorization.expression('!isAuthenticated()')" (template: "common/navbar" - line 24, col 25)] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method expression(java.lang.String) on null context object
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.throwIfNotNullSafe(MethodReference.java:153)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueRef(MethodReference.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:67)**
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am new to Thymeleaf and Spring security. So not sure why the Spring security is failing.

If i comment the line with authorization.expression(), it works.

I have shared the code at https://github.com/azaveri7/devopsbuddy in branch security.

Please advise.

Comment: Spring boot will automatically secure your urls with login if it finds spring security dependency in class path ,all you have to do is customize it ,like which urls shouldnt be restricted or your custom login page.You should check is authenticated in your controller rather than using it in thymeleaf templates.

Answer (score 0):

please consider this as a suggestion, not an answer. previously I also went through this but hard to figure it out. then I decided to go through spring's automatic configurations. I only used this library -

```
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
       </dependency>
```

and then spring provided the login URL, login page, logout URL etc.. I only wrote the userdetailsService. and in my case, I also wrote a custom filter also.

Answer (score 0):

I have the below to check if user is not logged-in or not

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

....

```
    <span sec:authorize="not isAuthenticated()">
         You are not logged in - click <a th:href="@{/login}">login</a>
    </span>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The spring security is 5.0.9 in your pom that extend the spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.6

**BUT thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4** is still spring security 4, so you need to upgrade the  thymeleaf-extras to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```